# JS input control for proportion, a widget to allocate proportion to more then 3 elements?

Tags: javascript, html, input, widget

I want to request data from a user, with the following question:

> What part of your salary do you spend on food, phone bills... electricity, travel?

I only need the percentage; What type of control should I present to the user so that the proportion is easily allocated?

I was thinking for a resizable chart. Pie chart? I don't know how usable it will be.

Any ideas or expirience of such things?