# Modify data through chart manipulation

Tags: web, charts, highcharts

Are there any charting libraries for the web that allow the user to manipulate the chart and update the backing data cleanly?

My idea of how it would work:

1. The chart definition is passed to the charting library
2. The chart is rendered on the webpage
3. The user modifies the chart(ie. add a point, drag a column)
4. The chart definition is sent back to the web server (ajax call), which then updates the data model

For example, I'd like to be able to drag any one of [these stacked columns](http://jsfiddle.net/b8mKf/) and update the backing json.

Partial Initial Chart Definition

```
seriesA: [
         {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
            }]
```

Partial Modified Chart Definition ( Note the difference in the first data point)

```
seriesA: [
         {
        data: [130.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2]
            }]
```

It seems possible to implement this through highcharts api: [Google Line Chart: drag to adjust value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847824/google-line-chart-drag-to-adjust-value/8960475#8960475) but I'm curious if there are any charting solutions that have a cleaner API for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual options in general are available at `chart.options`, see example with draggable plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/767/

Comment: do you have any insights as to why highcharts and js charting libraries in general have not included this feature as core functionality?